# Sort String Numbers

Tags: php, mysql, string, sorting, numbers

I have a column of type varchar that stores many different numbers. 
Say for example see the picture [image]

It should short as

`12-1`

`12-13`

`12-105`

`12-127`

`12-168`

Thanks

Comment: And how should it be sorted? Is it always 95 at the end? what does that format mean?

Comment: Didn't get the question. Please give more explanation and what did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1You can try something like that:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(row_name, '-', 1) as some_sort
FROM table_name
ORDER BY some_sort
```

So i guess (not tested, but idea in that way) : 
`12-34`,`12-46`,`12-95`,`12-135`...etc

But question quality is low, so i can only guess what u want to do.

Comment: sorry for the question quality :(

Comment: if not. just look for [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) to find out a way to choose needed postfix. But the idea is correct anyway :)